# Cannot extract WebSocket Sampler response and store as variable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to test our API on WS using WebSocket Sampler(Maciej Zaleski)

I want to extract the response from the first API and store the matched pattern as
variable, then pass it to the next request

But I failed and failed again on getting empty result

[image: 1]

[image: 1]

[image: 1]

Comment: Please update your response in you question from which you want to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract by regular expression you need to find a group, 
Group is found using () which you are missing.

In your case use Regular Expression: `FH(\d{5}-\d{7})`

Also you need to provide Template,in your case for first group, use `$1$`